# MySQL - Query with LEFT JOIN and group by not returning rows for count 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running below mentioned query.

```
select c.id, c.code, c.name, count(a.iso_country) from countries c 
left join airports a on c.code = a.iso_country group by a.iso_country 
order by count(a.iso_country);
```

In my 'countries' table, I have 247 rows.
In 'airports' table, 'iso_country' column maps to 'code' column in 'countries' table.

Below are the table definitions.
Countries table -

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`name` text,
`continent` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `code_UNIQUE` (`code`),
KEY `code_idx` (`code`)
)
```

Airports table -

```
CREATE TABLE `airports` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`type` text,
`name` text,
`continent` text,
`iso_country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`iso_region` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `country_iso_code_fk_idx` (`iso_country`),
CONSTRAINT `country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`iso_country`) REFERENCES `countries` 
(`code`) )
```

The issue I'm facing is - the query I mentioned above returns 242 countries - 241 countries with airports and 1 with null values for 'airports', but doesn't include other 5 countries who also don't have any airports. Please guide me what am I doing wrong in this query.

PS:- I am just a novice in SQL.

I'm running on MySQL 5.7 Community Edition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you group it with iso_country ?? you want to group it by country ?

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan - Yes, I want to count airports for each country. 'iso_country' column of 'airports' table maps to 'code' column of 'countries' table.

Comment: so i think first of all it's better that group it by code field on 'countries' table , and fix your order with that change , instead of 'count(a.iso_country)' use 'count(*)'

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan - you're right. group by should be on 'countries'.code, but count(a.iso_country) is needed so that I can get to know that for a country, whether it contains 0 airports.

Comment: Side comment: Why store continent in both tables?

Comment: @jeffcarey - this is some data I have been given to work on. :(

Comment: See my answer below. Your query as written above will result in an error since you are attempting to display fields not in the group by clause

Comment: @jeffcarey - MySQL allows you to select columns not in 'group by' clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a count of airports by country, including those where there are none, right?

Try this:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.code, c.name, count(a.iso_country) AS airport_count
FROM
    countries c LEFT JOIN airports a ON c.code = a.iso_country
GROUP BY
    c.id, c.code, c.name
ORDER BY
    airport_count DESC;
```

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for spotting that, I had left it in from the question. Agreed it is not needed and have updated my answer.

Comment: Pleasure. Us Carey's have to look out for each other ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with NULL values? Your `a.iso_country` column is `DEFAULT NULL` and `c.code` is `NOT NULL`. Usually when comparing values, if either can be `NULL`, you want to use something like `COALESCE` to provide a second option in the case that the value is `NULL`. The reason for this being that `NULL != ''` and `NULL != 0`. What if you join on `COALESCE(a.iso_country, '') = COALESCE(c.code, '')`?

I'm also not sure how `COUNT` behaves when given a `NULL`. You may need to be careful there.

Comment: select * from airports where iso_country IS NULL;
Its output is 0 row(s) returned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with checking this condition in the where clause .Implicitly checking null in table where airport are not found.

```
where (airports.name.is null)
```